# How to get rid of annoying blank line at beginning of method

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm missing a setting in the `Keep maximum blank lines` section of the Editor's code style.

```
public void foo(String s) {

    if (s == null) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I would like the formatter to remove the leading blank line but to keep the blank line in the middle.

One can remove blank lines `Before '}'`.

[image: Code Style]

I would appreciate a `After '{'`

Comment: There is no such setting. If you want to file a feature request for IntelliJ IDEA, please head over to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I opened issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196600